# socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, sockets, irc

```
 if data.find('!scan') != -1:
 nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':','')
 targetip = socket.gethostbyname(str(arg))
 sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" ' scanning host' + targetip + '\r\n')
 for i in range(20, 1025):
     s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
     result = s.connect_ex((targetip, i))
     if (result == 0) :
          s.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" 'port %d: OPEN' % (i,) + '\r\n')
     s.close()
```

I get this error:

```
    targetip = socket.gethostbyname(str(arg))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific what your question is and give some additional info?  What is in arg?  Are you sure you have access to your DNS server?  What have you done so far to try and fix this problem?

Comment: @Robert S. Barnes  arg is the argument a user gives after !scan.. example: !scan IP

Comment: What is the value of `arg`? Do you have your resolvers setup correctly?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, `socket.gethostbyname()` invokes the `getaddrinfo()` Winsock API call, and errno 11003 - [WSANO_RECOVERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSANO_RECOVERY) may be caused by the SYSTEMROOT environment variable not being set.

Check if os.environ contains SYSTEMROOT before calling socket.gethostbyname, ex:

```
import os
assert 'SYSTEMROOT' in os.environ
```